# Evento "onclick" solo funciona en un único elemento td, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, internet-explorer-8

Estoy realizando una tarea cuyo objetivo es hacer que funcione correctamente en Internet Explorer 8. Funciona correctamente en otros navegadores e incluso en IE11, pero en IE8 funciona regular.

El objetivo de esta tarea es crear una aplicación para pintar sobre elementos td que serán pintados cuando pasemos el ratón por encima.

Funciona en todos los exploradores, excepto en IE8 (requisito de la tarea). El fallo que tengo es que, al pasar el ratón por encima de los td, solo me pinta el último td.

La función que me está dando el fallo está en la línea 111 de .js; he probado a sacar mensajes en la consola, y los mensajes que recibo no parecen tener fallos.

La primera imagen es hecha de IE11, la segunda es de IE8 y no importa donde pase el ratón, solo me coge la referencia del último elemento td.

[image: Internet Explorer 11; FUNCIONA!]

[image: Internet Explorer 8; NO FUNCIONA :(]

Código .js .css y .html respectivamente. La función que no funciona del todo bien en Internet explorer es la última, llamada pintarCeldas.

```js
  //variables iniciales
  var selectColor;
  var estadoPincel = false;


//Introducimos el texto que sale en el enunciado de la tarea.
function crearTabla (){
  //Creamos un texto para adecuarnos a lo que sale en la imagen.
  var nuevoParrafo = document.createElement('p');
  var nuevoTexto = document.createTextNode('Haga CLICK en cualquier celda para activar/desactivar el Pincel');
  nuevoParrafo.appendChild(nuevoTexto);
  nuevoParrafo.setAttribute('class','pruebaAtributo');
  document.getElementById('zonadibujo').appendChild(nuevoParrafo);

  //creamos la tabla
  var nuevaTabla = document.createElement('table');
  nuevaTabla.setAttribute('class','tablerodibujo');
  for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++)
  {
    var nuevaFila = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var y = 0; y < 30; y++)
    {
      nuevaCelda = document.createElement('td');
      nuevaCelda.setAttribute("id","celda (" + (x+1) + ", " + (y+1) + ")");
      if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      {
        nuevaCelda.classList.add('color6');
        nuevaCelda.addEventListener('mouseover', pintarCeldas, false);
      }
      else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
      {
        var fx = function()
        {
          pintarCeldas.call(nuevaCelda);
        };
        nuevaCelda.className += "color6";
        nuevaCelda.attachEvent("onmouseover", fx);
      }
      nuevaFila.appendChild(nuevaCelda);
    }
    nuevaTabla.appendChild(nuevaFila);
  }
  if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
    nuevaTabla.addEventListener('mousedown', activarPintar, false);
  else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
  {
    var fx = function()
    {
      activarPintar.call(nuevaTabla);
    };
    nuevaTabla.attachEvent("onmousedown", fx);
  }
  document.getElementById('zonadibujo').appendChild(nuevaTabla);

  //cambiamos el estado del Pincel
  document.getElementById("pincel").childNodes[0].nodeValue = cambiarEstadoPincel(estadoPincel);

  //Le creamos a cada celda de la primera tabla el evento onClick
  selectColor = document.getElementById("paleta").getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < selectColor.length; i++)
    asignarClickCeldas(selectColor[i],true);
}


function cambiarEstadoPincel(estado)
{
  return estado? "PINCEL ACTIVADO" : "PINCEL DESACTIVADO";
}


//para signar a las celdas de color la propiedad de onClick()
function asignarClickCeldas(objeto, esSelColor){
  if (esSelColor)
    if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      objeto.addEventListener('click', seleccionarColor, false);
    else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
    {
      var fx = function()
      {
        seleccionarColor.call(objeto);
      };
      objeto.attachEvent("onclick", fx);
    }
}


//La función que ejecutaremos al hacer click en los colores
function seleccionarColor(miEvento)
{
  if (this.className.indexOf(' ') == -1)
  {
    //quito el elemento que esté seleccionado
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      if (this.className.indexOf(' ') == -1)
        selectColor[i].className = selectColor[i].className.replace(" seleccionado","");
    //selecciona el elemento clicado
    this.className = this.className + " seleccionado";
  }
}


//función que usaremos para activar pintar
function activarPintar(miEvento)
{
  estadoPincel = !estadoPincel;
  document.getElementById("pincel").childNodes[0].nodeValue = cambiarEstadoPincel(estadoPincel);
}


//función que usaremos para pintarCeldas
function pintarCeldas(miEvento)
{
  if (estadoPincel)
  {
    if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      var color = document.getElementsByClassName('seleccionado')[0];
    else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
      var color = document.querySelectorAll(".seleccionado")[0];
    var colorActual = color.className.replace(" seleccionado","");
    this.className = colorActual;
    console.log(colorActual);
    console.log(this.className);
  }
}
```

```css
.tablerodibujo {
 border-top-width: thin;
 border-right-width: thin;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-left-width: thin;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-left-style: solid;
 width: auto;
}
.tablerodibujo td {
 width: 10px;
 height:10px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.color1 {
 background-color: #FF0;
}
.color2 {
 background-color: #0F0;
}
.color3 {
 background-color: #000;
}
.color4 {
 background-color: #F00;
}
.color5 {
 background-color: #06C;
}
.color6 {
 background-color: #FFF;
}

#paleta td{
 width: 35px;
 height: 20px;
}

#pincel{
 text-align: center;
}

.seleccionado{
 border: medium solid #939;
}

.pruebaAtributo{
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DWEC06 - SOLUCION TAREA</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="DWEC06_SOLTAREA_estilos.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="DWEC06-TAREA.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="crearTabla()">
  <p>TABLERO DE DIBUJO EN JAVASCRIPT</p>
  <table width="500" border="1" id="paleta" summary="Tabla de selección de colores">
    <caption>
      Haga click en un color para comenzar a pintar
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <td class="color1 seleccionado"></td>
      <td class="color2"></td>
      <td class="color3"></td>
      <td class="color4"></td>
      <td class="color5"></td>
      <td class="color6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" id="pincel">Estado del pincel</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p></p>
  <div id="zonadibujo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo he solucionado!

Tenía una función **asignarClickCeldas()** que añadía un evento a un elemento que le pasase, mejoré un poco la función para que aceptase cualquier tipo de evento.

Función antes:

```js
//para signar a las celdas de color la propiedad de onClick()
function asignarClickCeldas(objeto, esSelColor){
  if (esSelColor)
    if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      objeto.addEventListener('click', seleccionarColor, false);
    else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
    {
      var fx = function()
      {
        seleccionarColor.call(objeto);
      };
      objeto.attachEvent("onclick", fx);
    }
}
```

Función después:

```js
//para asignar a las celdas de color la propiedad de onClick() y onMouseover()
function asignarClickCeldas(objeto, event, func){
  if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
    objeto.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
  {
    var fx = function()
    {
      func.call(objeto);
    };
    objeto.attachEvent("on" + event, fx);
  }
}
```

De modo que eliminé el código de asignación de evento que tenía en **crearTabla()** y añadí un nuevo for al final de esta para que fuera añadiendo el evento mouseover a cada elemento td. Hace exactamente lo mismo que el otro código, pero añade el evento mouseover al elemento td cuando este ya ha sido añadido a la tabla.

```js
function crearTabla (){
  //Creamos un texto para adecuarnos a lo que sale en la imagen.
  var nuevoParrafo = document.createElement('p');
  var nuevoTexto = document.createTextNode('Haga CLICK en cualquier celda para activar/desactivar el Pincel');
  nuevoParrafo.appendChild(nuevoTexto);
  nuevoParrafo.setAttribute('class','pruebaAtributo');
  document.getElementById('zonadibujo').appendChild(nuevoParrafo);

  //creamos la tabla
  var nuevaTabla = document.createElement('table');
  nuevaTabla.setAttribute('class','tablerodibujo');
  for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++)
  {
    var nuevaFila = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var y = 0; y < 30; y++)
    {
      var nuevaCelda = document.createElement('td');
      nuevaCelda.setAttribute("id","celda (" + (x+1) + ", " + (y+1) + ")");
      if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      {
        nuevaCelda.classList.add('color6');
        nuevaCelda.addEventListener('mouseover', pintarCeldas, false);
      }
      else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
        nuevaCelda.className += "color6";
      nuevaFila.appendChild(nuevaCelda);
    }
    nuevaTabla.appendChild(nuevaFila);
  }

  //Añadimos el evento mousedown a la tabla y la añadimos a la zona de dibujo
  if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
    nuevaTabla.addEventListener('mousedown', activarPintar, false);
  else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
  {
    var fx = function()
    {
      activarPintar.call(nuevaTabla);
    };
    nuevaTabla.attachEvent("onmousedown", fx);
  }
  document.getElementById('zonadibujo').appendChild(nuevaTabla);

  //cambiamos el estado del Pincel
  document.getElementById("pincel").childNodes[0].nodeValue = cambiarEstadoPincel(estadoPincel);

  //Le creamos a cada celda de la segunda tabla el evento onMouseover
  if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
      selectColor = document.getElementById("zonadibujo").getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
      for (var j = 0; j < selectColor.length; j++)
        asignarClickCeldas(selectColor[j], "mouseover", pintarCeldas);
    }

  //Le creamos a cada celda de la primera tabla el evento onClick
  selectColor = document.getElementById("paleta").getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < selectColor.length; i++)
    asignarClickCeldas(selectColor[i], "click", seleccionarColor);  
}
```

Y este código, respecto al anterior, funciona en Internet Explore 8 porque... eh... pues.......
Porque obviamente... ehhhh... ¡¡¡Pues Debido a la Existencia del CORONAVIRUS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tu función tiene el siguiente código

```
function pintarCeldas(miEvento) {
  if (estadoPincel) {
    if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined")
      var color = document.getElementsByClassName('seleccionado')[0];
    else if (typeof window.attachEvent !== "undefined")
      var color = document.querySelectorAll(".seleccionado")[0];
    var colorActual = color.className.replace(" seleccionado","");
    this.className = colorActual;
    console.log(colorActual);
    console.log(this.className);
  }
}
```

IE8 es *muy antiguo* y tiene muchas limitaciones:

- La función `document.getElementsByClassName` no está soportada por IE8
- La función `document.querySelectorAll` sólo funciona si **no** estás en *quirks mode*, asegúrate de que tienes un doctype bien definido: `<!DOCTYPE html>` o el navegador entrará en modo "compatibilidad con IE7" y no existirá.

Supongo que necesitas que funcione en máquinas con Windows XP, pero yo intentaría convencer a quien exija esta retrocompatibilidad que use un navegador más moderno, tanto Chrome como Firefox tienen versiones más modernas compatibles con ese SO.

Comment: - lo del document.getElementsByClassName ya sabía, por eso tengo puesto el if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined"), pues si el navegador no tiene definido el addEventListener, hará el otro if.

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo del quirks mode, pero ciertamente la función document.querySelectorAll funciona correctamente, pues los siguientes console.log me muestran la información que deberían correctamente. Ya le hemos propuesto a la profesora la alternativa de quemar los ordenadores en el mundo que solo usen IE8, pero no ha funcionado   :( El problema que veo es que, al pasar el ratón sobre las celdas, el evento solo me pilla el último td de toda la tabla.